# Union intersected nested lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for an efficient way to union intersected nested lists. 
Ex:

```
input: [[1,2,3], [5,3,7],[8,9]]
output: [[1,2,3,5,7],[8,9]]
```

Note: assume more than three nested lists

Current implementation:
Loop over each nested list --> loop over all lists --> if there is an intersection, union and delete old list -- do that until no intersection.

Comment: If you don't care about the order of list items you can use sets instead which support the usual set operations.

Comment: Are the elements in the inner lists sortable?

Comment: Let's say (as in your example) your lists are sorted. That could help, because if list[i][-1] < list[j][0] then you know that lists i and j do not intersect. Furthermore, you know that for m <= i and n => j, lists m and n do not intersect either.

Comment: Not sorted, could be a mix e.g int and string

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So I thought of something else: this problem reduces to finding the connected components in a (particular bipartite) graph: You have two types of vertices: 1. sublists 2. elements of those sublists. There is an edge from a sublist to an element iff that sublist contains that element. There are well known and efficient algorithms for finding the connect components of a graph, so I will not reiterate them here.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure how fast this is (let me think about it), but I think this works (I tested it on a few different inputs, including your example, and got correct results):

```
def merge_intersecting_elements(many_lists):
    # Let lst in claims.values()
    # claims[e] is lst iff e in lst.
    claims = {}

    for lst in many_lists:
        glob = lst[:]
        for e in lst:
            if e not in claims:
                claims[e] = glob  # We are the first to claim e.
                continue

            # Ignore self-intersection.
            if claims[e] is glob:
                continue

            # We found someone else that we intersect with.
            # Take over ALL their territory, not just e.
            glob.extend(claims[e])
            for e2 in claims[e]:
                claims[e2] = glob  # at some point, e2 = e

    deduper = {}
    for v in claims.values():
        deduper[id(v)] = v

    return list(deduper.values())
```

So... One thing about this solution is that it maintains multiplicity. Based on your example, seems like you do not want that. Relatedly, it also seems that within each input sublist, each element is supposed to be unique, but you also didn't specify this.

In any case, I think it should be easy to adapt my suggested solution to maintain uniqueness, though it might affect performance. At the very least, you could uniquify each sublist at the end (which can be accelerated by sorting).

Update: I think you can speed up my solution by changing

```
for lst in many_lists
```

to

```
for lst in sorted(many_lists, key=len, reverse=True)
```

This would tend to reduce the total amount of time spent in the inner most loop, although I think it depends on exactly what data you feed in.

Here's the basic intuition why sorting by length in descending order would be helpful. Consider this degenerate example:

```
mother_lode = list(range(n))
[[0], [1], [2], [3], ... [n], mother_lode]
```

If the first lst is mother_lode, then EVERYBODY collides with it and so we end up scanning a large list many times. But, if instead we consider mother_lode LAST, then we only rescan many small lists once. This adds up to n times less (total) rescanning time.